# Terminal stuck on installing ri documentation for rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, installation

OSX Mavericks, trying to upgrade from Rails 4.0.4 to either 4.1.0.beta1 or 4.1.0.rc2 with ruby version ruby 2.1.1p76 (2014-02-24 revision 45161) [x86_64-darwin12.0].

In both instances (beta1 and rc1 builds), Terminal gets stuck at  Installing ri documentation for rails-4.1.0.rc2

and I have to quit the process (command + > ).

Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe try again with the official 4.1.0 release?

Comment: In case anyone is interested in how long it takes. It was +30 min in my case for ri. And then another +30min for RDoc when its installation time comes.

Comment: It took me two good minutes almost. (I installed it via `brew`)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This has happened to me a few times. I believe it is a [known issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/11814) which has never been resolved properly.

Simply install the gem without the documentation, if you don't mind, like the other answer suggests.

```
gem install rails --no-ri --no-rdoc
```

**UPDATE (2020-04-29)**

The new way of generating no documentation is adding the `--no-document (in short -N)` option, like so:

```
gem install rails --no-document # or -N in short
```

Comment: It might not be hung.   It can take a while, in some instances of up to 10 minutes.  See @Mike's answer

Comment: I was updating `fastlane` and got stucked. For me I just `ctrl-c` and did update again and it worked fine.

Answer (score 11):

Are you sure it's stuck? The documentation takes ages to install (upwards of 4 mins even on a high end MBPr). You could also install the rails gem without documentation using:

`gem install --no-ri --no-rdoc rails`

Comment: I was so close to quitting the process, but you're right it just took ~10 mins and finally finished.