# Install Ruby on Rails on Linux Mint 17

Tags: ruby, linux, installation, rvm

I have been struggling this task. I have been developing in php but want to switch to ruby. My question is how do I install ruby on rails on Linux Mint 17.

Comment: Sort of. The equivalent to a lamp stack is generally rails.

Comment: What have you used for php? It runs programms in exactly same way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After installing rvm, just type `gem install rails` and you are ready with rails.

For an IDE I think a popular choice is [RubyMine](http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/) and if you are into text editors you can try using [Vim](http://www.vim.org/) or another popular choice [Sublime text editor](http://www.sublimetext.com/).

I would recommend using editor in the beginning, just to get used to the terminal and all the ruby tools out there like `rails`, `rake`, `rspec` etc.

Answer (score 1):

Simply put, to install ruby on rails on this OS. You should follow

- http://railsapps.github.io/installrubyonrails-ubuntu.html
- http://users.drew.edu/bburd/rubyonrails/InstallingRoRinLinux.pdf

Answer (score 1):

I just installed `ruby2.2` & `rail4.2` on mint mate 17 via `rvm` & `gem`.

**Steps:**

- **[install rvm]**
- open vim
- \curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
- reopen a vim
- rvm -v
- **[install ruby]**
- sudo apt-get purge ruby *(this will remove old ruby that is not installed by rvm)*
- rvm list known *(this will show available ruby versions)*
- rvm install 2.2.0 *(it's quite smart, will do a lot check, might take a while)*
- setup GEM_HOME, and choose ruby version via `rvm use ruby-2.2.0` *(I didn't use this way, for some reason)*
- or, put `~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/bin` to your PATH, by hand, *(I use this way, because I have a common config file for such things)*
- reboot or re-login or `source some_file`, *(depends on your configuration)*
- ruby -v
- **[install rails]**
- gem install rails *(install to "current_ruby/bin/" inside rvm folder,)*
- rails -v
- done

---

**Issues**

- When install rails, it might stuck at "Installing ri documentation for rails". Solution: just stop it, and execute `gem install rails` again. Or refer to [A discussion on stackoverflow about this issue.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22945924/terminal-stuck-on-installing-ri-documentation-for-rails)